# Yelp Fusion API v3 returns 401 Unauthorized with TOKEN_MISSING error when called from c#

Tags: c#, api, restsharp, yelp, unauthorized

I've created my app in Yelp, got my api key, and things work fine from Postman when executing a business search.

However, when testing from c#, I receive a 401 unauthorized error with a TOKEN_MISSING error that says ""{\"error\": {\"code\": \"TOKEN_MISSING\", \"description\": \"An access token must be supplied in order to use this endpoint.\"}}"".

I'm supplying my api key correctly though, and the Yelp documentation says that's all I need, so I'm not sure what the problem is.  Here are 2 separate c# code samples that do NOT work (I've replaced my actual api key with  for security concerns):

Example using WebRequest:

```
var webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=Clayton+Bicycle+Center&location=5411+Clayton+Rd%2c+Clayton%2c+CA+94517%2c+US");
webRequest.Method = "GET";
webRequest.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer <my_api_key>");
HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
var stream = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
var content = stream.ReadToEnd();
Console.Write(content);
```

Example using RestSharp:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=Clayton+Bicycle+Center&location=5411+Clayton+Rd%2c+Clayton%2c+CA+94517%2c+US");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer <my_api_key>");
var response = client.Execute(request);
Console.Write(response.Content);
```

I've examined the requests in Fiddler, and both are sending the same headers as the working Postman search, but both return 401 unauthorized error while Postman returns the search results.  Any ideas?

Edit:

Well this is embarrassing, apparently my issue was I was attempting to access the Yelp API via http instead of https.  Once I changed to https, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Changed endpoint to use https instead of http, works now.